# Custom the value of Member attribute in Umbraco member list

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, umbraco, umbraco7

I'm trying to customize the display of **member attribute in Umbraco member list**.
For example, I want to change the **status string** (pictures below). Is there any official way to do that?

**Actual:**
[image: umbraco member list actual]

**Expected:**
[image: umbraco member list expected]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out that I can create another tab in Member section follow this documents:

**Umbraco extending**:

1. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/extending/
2. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Tutorials/Creating-a-Custom-Dashboard/
3. https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/Tutorials/creating-a-property-editor/part-4

**Routing:**

https://our.umbraco.com/documentation/reference/routing/webapi/

**Migration:**

https://cultiv.nl/blog/using-umbraco-migrations-to-deploy-changes/